# Problem with website not loading (using dynamic ip update client with Ubuntu server)

Tags: webserver

I am having trouble with getting the url from my web server to load.

It is likely not the issue, but I will mention for completeness that I am using the noip dynamic update client to map my public IP address to a domain (call it example.ddns.net). 
https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/ 
I can ssh fine into example.ddns.net, which seems to indicate that the dynamic client is working fine.

However, when I type the url example.ddns.net into a browser, it just hangs and I eventually get the error "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" (this is using firefox on windows, but also fails using internet explorer).

I had been able to successfully load the page in a browser for months. I haven't changed the permission settings or any of the files in the /var/www folder in the past month (other than one file which I made a minor change to recently). So I don't see any reason to think there was a hack.

The only significant thing that has changed is that I recently posted a link to the url example.ddns.net publicly. I see with "sudo service ssh status" that I've gotten a bunch of random IP addresses attempting to hack into the server, possibly from bots after I posted it publicly (I didn't really check previously so I'm not sure how many of these attacks I got before). But from what I hear this is pretty standard, so I am not sure if these attempted hacks are the problem (I have recently installed fail2ban to help with that issue).

Comment: If the update client was not working, then both SSH and Web would fail. Consider editing your title and question to focus on diagnosing the webserver.

Comment: Should I post this on another forum if it is more of a webserver issue than specific to Ubuntu/DUC? It is hard for me to know which issues are relevant in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: This forum is fine, just edit your question once you have proved to yourself that the update client is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it had to do with the apache server.

I typed sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
Then killed the process and restarted the server with "sudo service apache2 start"